# Jasperserver source code build Issues

Tags: java, maven, jasperserver

I am trying to build JasperServer from source code (6.3.0). I am getting the following Error. Can anyone please help me with this.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project jasperserver-api-metadata:

 Could not resolve dependencies for project com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata:jasperserver-api-metadata:jar:6.3.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: jaspersoft.ji-pro.ji-jpivot-ui:ji-jpivot:jar:6.1.0, org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.3.2.GA-HHH-2763, org.olap4j:olap4j-xmla:jar:1.1.0-JS-6, pentaho:mondrian:jar:3.6.4-JS-2: 

 Could not find artifact jaspersoft.ji-pro.ji-jpivot-ui:ji-jpivot:jar:6.1.0 in js-repo-svn (file://C:\Source\Scala\jasperserver-repo)

 [java] [ERROR]
 [java] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
 [java] [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
 [java] [ERROR]
 [java] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
 [java] [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
 [java] [ERROR]
 [java] [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
 [java] [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :jasperserver-api-metadata
 [java] Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=32m; support was removed in 8.0
 [java] Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you read http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException? Did you make sure all dependencies are met? Are you compiling a package, from where did you get it?

Comment: I have followed the same procedure @ "https://docs.tibco.com/pub/js-rptsrvr-amxbpm/6.2.0/doc/TIB_js-rptsrvr-amxbpm_6.2.0_Source_Build.pdf", on page-17, when i  am Builds the community source code using  'js-ant build-ce', am getting this issue